# @material-ui/data-grid Use checkboxSelection but still select one row at a time when clicking on row

Tags: material-ui, datagrid, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

I am trying to select a row in the data grid but while having checkbox selection enabled when clicking on a different row it adds the row to the selection. I would like that behavior only when clicking on the checkbox. Is there a way to do single selection if clicking on the row and multiple selection when clicking on the checkbox ?

I already tried disableMultipleRowSelection={true} and I expected to indeed disableMultipleRowSelection. However if checkboxSelection is present it is always multiple row selection.